# Use ELB to Serve Multiple SSL Domains on one EC2 Instance and same Public IP

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, virtualhost, amazon-elb

We are  using One AWS EC2 instance to host multiple sites and separate ELBs to Serve Multiple SSL Domains for each site.

Before applying the ELBs with AWS SSL certificates for each domain , the virtual hosts are working well.

We use Amazon Route 53 to point every domain to its ELB.

Apache virtual hosts configuration.

```
DocumentRoot "/usr/domain1/"
ServerName domain1.com
ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
```

```
DocumentRoot "/usr/domain2"
ServerName domain2.com
ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
```

The problem that both ELBs are redirecting to the first site always?
How I can fix the issue so that the second ELB point to its domain2.com ?

Comment: ELB (Classic) is not capable of generating redirects at all.  ELB v2 (Application Load Balancer, ALB) is capable, but will not generate redirects unless you specifically configure it to.  The conclusion then is that your server must be doing this, and you should find evidence of the redirects in the server's log.  The first thing I would suggest is that you confirm this, so that we are troubleshooting the correct problem.

Comment: When I request domain 1 it is working well. but when I request the domain 2 it will be directed to domain 1